# Scanning and SSL Bypass Options

Tags: tls

I'm looking at implementing SSL Interception on my local firewall, as well as implementing URL filtering.

How would I be able to tell if a site was being 'blocked' or not accessible because of the SSL interception piece, as apposed to any other type of block in place.

Comment: I think the answer to this question would depend entirely on how you implement both the SSL intercept and the URL filtering.

Answer (score 0):

In the corporate world, most web filters are configured to throw up an informative banner to the user.

If you view the certs you may see the intercept cert. Remember, SSL intercept is just a politically correct name for "man in the middle".